# C# OrderBy List By Associated Table

Tags: c#, sql-order-by

In C# (for an ASP.net MVC application) I am looking to do an OrderBy function on data from my database, however I would like to base it on an associated tables values. Here is a simplified example:

My primary table:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ContactId { get; set; }
}
```

and the associated Contact table

```
public class Contact
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName{ get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I can get a list of all my Person entries as follows:

```
sortList = db.People.ToList();
```

I have no problem sorting sortList by something in the primary table, say ContactId, but I would like to sort by the associated table.

I would like to sort sortList by the associated last name (from the Contact table), where `Person.ContactId = Contact.Id`. Most likely I would like to use the `OrderBy` function. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: First join Person+Contact (however this is done in said LINQ sources) and then OrderBy a derived/accessible field therein. Delay using ToList if possible, as that can prevent promotion of the operation (including the join) to lower levels.

Comment: The following will return the correct result, but I cannot figure out how to turn it into a People List:          var cont = db.Contacts;
          var combList = db.People.Select( e => new { Person = e, Contact = cont.FirstOrDefault( q => q.Id == e.ContactId ) } ).OrderBy( e => e.Contact.FirstName ).ToList();

Comment: `.Select(e => e.Person)`

Comment: Okay I solved it, not sure if it is the most efficient way but it does seem to work: var personList = from i in db.Person
                             join o in db.Contacts
                             on i.ContactId equals o.Id
                             orderby o.LastName
                             select i;

          List<Person> peopleList = personList.ToList();

Comment: That looks sufficient; and is what I was alluding to my first comment. Look at the generated SQL (if such is used in the LINQ provider) and run some performance tests if/when there is a suspected concern. However I might change the variable names or omit `personList` entirely.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This worked, I'm not sure if it is the most efficient way:

```
var personList = from i in db.Person
                 join o in db.Contacts
                 on i.ContactId equals o.Id
                 orderby o.LastName
                 select i;

List<Person> peopleList = personList.ToList();
```